# Printing on a 80mm paper ( receipt ) on iOS

Tags: ios5

I would like to ask if how can i print an html set of string on a 80mm width paper on iOS. I'm planning on printing it on a thermal paper with the use of airprint and a receipt printer of course. Sorry if i can't give codes because i haven't started creating it yet i want to ask for advice on how to do this the right way. thanks.

Comment: There are quite a lot of details missing. Where is the printer connected? How? To which OS? If Windows does it have a Windows driver (WHQL or not)?

Comment: i'm using fingerPrint its a software which bridges the printer more likely airprint.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS you can render the html to an image context or PDF document using Core Graphics. 
In case of PDF specify the paper size in `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo`. You need to do some calculation because the print resolution is 72 dpi (80 mm = 3.15 inch -> 72*3.15 = 226.8 points).

Save the result in a file (or in a `NSData` or `UIImage`).
Then you can print this document over air print:

```
UIPrintInteractionController* pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pdfPath];
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.jobName = @"Receipt";
pic.printInfo = printInfo;
pic.printingItem = fileURL; // single NSData, NSURL, UIImage or ALAsset

[pic presentAnimated:YES
   completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
           // ...
   }];
```

Of course, your printing device needs to support air print somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Star Micronics has a receipt printer iOS SDK you can get here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

This package provides a printing API which handles your basic status, open/close port, and printer communication, along with lots of samples to customize receipt output and documentation.

Comment: can i use it to connect to any POS printer not belonging to Star Micronics products?

Comment: No, this API is only for Star printers. I don't know of any manufacturer that provides an API which will work with any printer brand.